# Redirect after successful sign in or sign up for credentials type in next auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

Is there any examples and/or way to redirect to private dashboard on successful sign in or sign up for credentials type in `next-auth`?
I couldn't find any clear docs around this.

I was looking at adding redirect below but wasn't sure if it was the right approach:

```
callbacks.signIn = async (data, account, profile) => {
  if ((account.provider === 'google' && profile.verified_email === true) || (account.type === 'credentials' && data.status === 200)) {
    return Promise.resolve(true)
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve(false)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

This can actually happen when initiating the signin. From the [docs](https://next-auth.js.org/v3/getting-started/client#specifying-a-callbackurl)., you can pass a callback URL to the sign in. you code will look like this.

```
  signIn(provider.id, {
      callbackUrl: `${window.location.origin}/protected`,
    })
```

Comment: doesn't work for conditionals redirects

Comment: can you give examples @JonasPraem

Comment: if you want to redirect dependent on the user data. Say they are authorized but don't have the right permissions, you can't define the callback url before you know the user data. The callback url works if you want all users to some destinations, but you will need custom code to handle if some users go to x and some to y.

Comment: Then you will need to redirect to a generic URL, determine the user data and then redirect appropriately. But I think There are other ways to achieve it, I might have to check the docs if the user data is passed here in the signIn.

Answer (score 0):

With the new versions of Next.js you can do the redirect on 'getStaticProps' method like the following,

Resource : https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  // some imperative work..


  //
  if (!user) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/', // some destination '/dashboard' Ex,
        permanent: false,
      },
    }
  }

  return {
    props: {},
  }
}
```

Comment: does it work on `[...nextauth].js` file aswell?

Comment: actually, it wont work because assuming the [...nextauth].js is placed in an api route, because that file name is for an api route.

Answer (score 0):

it is working for me like this

```
"use client";
import Link from "next/link";
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  // handle submit event
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const isLoggedin = await signIn(
        "credentials",
        {
          email,
          password,
        },
        { callbackUrl: "/dashboard/profile" }
      );

      if (isLoggedin.error !== null) {
        toast.error("Incorrect Login Details!!");
      } else {
        toast.success("Login Successful!!");
        // router.replace("/dashboard/profile");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      toast.success(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{ maxWidth: "480px" }}
      className="mt-10 mb-20 p-4 md:p-7 mx-auto rounded bg-white shadow-lg"
    >
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h2 className="mb-5 text-2xl font-semibold">Login</h2>

        <div className="mb-4">
          <label className="block mb-1"> Email </label>
          <input
            className="appearance-none border border-gray-200 bg-gray-100 rounded-md py-2 px-3 hover:border-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-400 w-full"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Type your email"
            required
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="mb-4">
          <label className="block mb-1"> Password </label>
          <input
            className="appearance-none border border-gray-200 bg-gray-100 rounded-md py-2 px-3 hover:border-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-400 w-full"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Type your password"
            minLength={6}
            required
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>

        <button
          type="submit"
          className="my-2 px-4 py-2 text-center w-full inline-block text-white bg-blue-600 border border-transparent rounded-md hover:bg-blue-700"
        >
          Login
        </button> 
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Comment: Please explain the solution, so readers of your answer will understand your thought process.

Comment: Hi!, can you provide your "authOptions"?

Answer (score 0):

## Using custom HTML

When using a custom login page this behavior is undocumented. However, the solution below is working like a charm for me.

To be clear, the other answers which have linked to the `callbackUrl` parameter in the `signIn`/`signOut` functions are sufficient if you're using that. [See the docs here](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#specifying-a-callbackurl) for those instructions.

This answer is for those using [`getCsrfToken`](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#getcsrftoken) in a custom POST request.

### Leverage a hidden `<input />` element

Below we'll use a hidden input element to send the `callbackUrl` in the form's POST submission.

> *Note: The following assumes you correctly acquire a `csrfToken`.*

```
<form
  id="email-login"
  method="post"
  action="/api/auth/signin/email"
>
  <input name="csrfToken" type="hidden" defaultValue={csrfToken} />
  <input name="callbackUrl" type="hidden" defaultValue="/dashboard" />
  <input
    label="email"
    id="email"
    name="email"
    type="email"
    required
  />
  <div>
    <button
      type="submit"
    >
      <span>
        Email login
      </span>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

In the snippet above, the key line is

```html
<input name="callbackUrl" type="hidden" defaultValue="/dashboard" />
```

This sends a `callbackUrl` body parameter in the POST request so that login will redirect the user to `your-site.tld/dashboard`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the built-in [`callbackUrl in signIn`](https://next-auth.js.org/v3/getting-started/client#specifying-a-callbackurl) is that it seems to redirect even when your login credentials are incorrect (atleast in my case)

I think a much simpler and cleaner approach would be to set `redirect: false` and handling the redirect yourself with `window.location.replace("...")` like this:

```
function validate_login(event) {

    event.preventDefault()

    signIn("credentials", {
        username: username_input.value,
        password: password_input.value,
        redirect: false, // this will prevent redirect
    })
        .then((result) => {

            if (result?.error)
                alert("Invalid Credentials!")
            else
                window.location.replace("/private_dashboard") // if login successful
        })
        .catch(err => {
            ...
        })
        .finally(() => {
            ...
        })
}
```

Here's a complete copy paste bare minimum example if you're lazy like me:

```
"use client"
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";

function validate_login(event: any) {

    event.preventDefault()

    const username_inp: HTMLInputElement = document.querySelector("#username")!
    const password_inp: HTMLInputElement = document.querySelector("#password")!
    const submit_btn: HTMLInputElement = document.querySelector(`#submit_btn`)!

    submit_btn.disabled = true

    signIn("credentials", {
        username: username_inp.value,
        password: password_inp.value,
        redirect: false,
    })
        .then((result) => {

            if (result?.error)
                alert("Invalid Credentials!")
            else
                window.location.replace("/user")
        })
        .catch(err => {
            alert(`Error Occured: ${err}`)
        })
        .finally(() => {
            submit_btn.disabled = false
        })
}

const LoginPage = () => {

    return (<form onSubmit={validate_login}>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" />

        <br />
        <br />

        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" />

        <br />
        <br />

        <input id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Submit"></input>

    </form>)
}

export default LoginPage;
```

[image]

**Note: This has been tested in Next.js 13**

Answer (score -1):

If you go to the Next-Auth documentation:
https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#signin

You would find the method signIn() accept a call back url.

This is the example base on Version, I'm using version 5

V4

```
const url = await signIn(provider, { redirect: false, redirectTo: '/dashboard' })
```

V5

```
...
'use server'
const url = await signIn(provider, { redirect: false, redirectTo: '/dashboard'})
...
```

Also, you can find more details inside the package.

```
signIn<
    P extends BuiltInProviderType | (string & {}),
    R extends boolean = true
  >(
    /** Provider to sign in to */
    provider?: P, // See: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29729
    options?: {
      /** The URL to redirect to after signing in. By default, the user is redirected to the current page. */
      redirectTo?: string
      /** If set to `false`, the `signIn` method will return the URL to redirect to instead of redirecting automatically. */
      redirect?: R
    } & Record<string, any>,
    authorizationParams?:
      | string[][]
      | Record<string, string>
      | string
      | URLSearchParams
  ): Promise<R extends false ? any : never>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!